# Select fields in mongoose query where field value not equal to something

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am basically trying to update a document and then select the fields from the result where the field value is not equal to something. Assume `jwt_id` to be `b816cf00e9f649fbaf613e2ca2d523b5`.

**Query**

```
const removeDevices = await Identity.findOneAndUpdate(
                    {
                        userID: user_id
                    },
                    {
                        $pull: {
                            activeTokens: {
                                jti: {
                                    $ne: jwt_id
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                ).select(["-_id", "activeTokens.jti"]);
```

Now, running this query gives the following output:

```
{ activeTokens:
   [ { jti: '5d872359af2c47e5970c1fae531adf0e' },
     { jti: 'd3ac84f520614067b1caad504d7ab27f' },
     { jti: '25c6fa96705c4eec96e1427678c3ff50' },
     { jti: 'b816cf00e9f649fbaf613e2ca2d523b5' } 
   ] 
}
```

How can I get all the `jti` fields except `{ jti: b816cf00e9f649fbaf613e2ca2d523b5 }` from the `select` command?

**Desired Output**

```
{ activeTokens:
       [ { jti: '5d872359af2c47e5970c1fae531adf0e' },
         { jti: 'd3ac84f520614067b1caad504d7ab27f' },
         { jti: '25c6fa96705c4eec96e1427678c3ff50' },
       ] 
    }
```

Comment: `{ $pull: { 'activeTokens.jti': jwt_id } }` try this as your update statement. you seem to be using `$ne` erroneously, since you intend to pull the `token` that matches the `jwt_id` and not vice versa

Comment: @r3wt, I intend to pull all other tokens except the one I pass. Think of a function to revoke all device tokens except the current one.

Comment: `{ $set: { activeTokens:[{jti:jwt_id}] } }`. Keep it simple, why mess with array operators when you can just overwrite the array? unless you need to have a list of the removed tokens for some reason, and if so i would just recommend doing a `findOne()`, manually updating in application code, then a `save()`. I end up doing this 99% of time due to the complexity of the find Statement and updateStatement making it impossible to use `$push/$pull`

Comment: I could have done that, but then it will remove other associated data with the jwt_id, such as refreshToken, deviceLocation etc. And also as you said, I am caching the removed tokens jti in redis.

Comment: @r3wt is there any way of using `$ne` with `select`? As the current query successfully removes the tokens except the current one. If I could use `$ne` somehow with `select` I can call it a day. Else, I would need to iterate over the returned array to remove the current jwt_id.

Comment: you might be able to do the `$ne` in your select, then use `activeTokens.$` in your update to pull from the array. what i'm not sure of is whether or not mongoose returns the document with the update applied or not ( i don't believe it does but could be wrong), so you are oging to have to filter in app code anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say for certain without testing, but i don't think mongoose returns the document after it was modified, but rather simply returns the matching document. So, i think in the case of `findOneAndUpdate`, you would have to have your query match to do the pull, and then manually filter the array again in application code to get the desired output.

This might work:

```
const removeDevices = await Identity.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        userID: user_id
    },
    {
        $pull: {
            'activeTokens.jti': { $ne: jwt_id }
        }
    },
).select(["-_id", "activeTokens.jti"]).then(identity=>identity.activeTokens.filter(token=>token.jti!==jwt_id));
```

If the above doesn't work for some reason, then i would try something more simpler

simple:

```
const removeDevices = await Identity.findOne({userID: user_id}).select(["-_id", "activeTokens"]).then(identity=>{
    const removedTokens = []
    identity.activeTokens = identity.activeTokens.filter(token=>{
        if(token.jti===jwt_id) {
            return true;
        }
        removedTokens.push(token);
    })
    identity.save(err=>{
        console.log('doc saved')
    });
    return removedTokens;
});
```

or (atomic):

```
const removeDevices = await Identity.findOne({userID: user_id}).select('activeTokens','jti _id').then(identity=>{
    const removedTokens = identity.activeTokens.filter(token=>token.jti!==jwt_id);
    const result = await Identity.update({userId:user_id},{$pull:{'activeTokens._id': { $in: removedTokens.map(t=>t._id) } }});
    console.log(result.nModified);
    return removedTokens;
});
```